# get a list of defined zend routes

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

so you can add routes in zend framework with Zend Router's addRoute() method...

but what if I want to get a list of all the defined routes? is there a method that I can use to do so?

Comment: Those are routes, not routers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the **Rewrite routing** you can call `getRoutes()` in `Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite`. This will give you an array of all chained routes.

Answer (score 0):

In **Zend Framework 1.11** you can get the router from the **Front Controller** like this:

```
$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
```

You can get the routes with the **getRoutes** method:

```
$routes = $router->getRoutes();
```